# Copy just the VALUES from cell AC7 to T7 down until the end of the data set

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
   LR = Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Range("AB7:AB" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-9]=""Debit"",""Credit"",""Debit"")"
   
   Dim num As Long
   LR = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Range("AC7:AC" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=abs(RC[-9])"
```

This is the bottom of my code. I am trying to get the results (JUST THE VALUES) of my last 3 lines of code to be pasted into cell T7 down until the end of the data.

Comment: Is T7 the first row of a table?

Comment: No it is the 2nd row. the 1st row is the title... and can you please refer me to a youtube channel or resource that I can use to learn Excel VBA code.... rows 1-5 are blank, because they contain the Pivot table

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I *do* have a solution!

When you have Rose and columns like that, you can highlight them, including the title row, and then click "Insert Table" from the data ribbon. (Or press control T)

Besides allowing you to format the entire table at a time, call him formulas can refer to other columns by name, and a column with one formula is stored as just one formula for that column regardless of how many rows! With this, you might not have to even do any coding at all to get this done, depending on your needs. ... or, if you do need VBA for some larger part, this answer might be useless. Feel free to ignore.

In VBA, tables are called ListObjects instead of "tables", for some reason. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject

Answer (score 0):

### Variable vs `With Statement`

**R1C1-Style**

```
Sub UsingVariableR1C1()
    Dim LR As Long: LR = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Declare a range variable.
    Dim rg As Range
    ' Create a reference to the range.
    Set rg = Range("AC7:AC" & LR).Offset(0, -9)
    ' Write formula.
    rg.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC[9])"
    ' Convert to values.
    rg.Value = rg.Value
End Sub

Sub UsingWithR1C1()
    Dim LR As Long: LR = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Create a reference to the range using the With statement.
    With Range("AC7:AC" & LR).Offset(0, -9)
        ' Write formula.
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC[9])"
        ' Convert to values.
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**A1-Style**

```vb
Sub UsingVariableA1()
    Dim LR As Long: LR = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Declare a range variable.
    Dim rg As Range
    ' Create a reference to the range.
    Set rg = Range("T7:T" & LR)
    ' Write formula.
    rg.Formula = "=ABS(AC7)"
    ' or: 
    'rg.Formula = "=ABS(" & rg.Cells(1).Offset(0, 9).Address(0,0) & ")"
    ' Convert to values.
    rg.Value = rg.Value
End Sub

Sub UsingWithA1()
    Dim LR As Long: LR = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Create a reference to the range using the With statement.
    With Range("T7:T" & LR)
        ' Write formula.
        .Formula = "=ABS(AC7)"
        ' or:
        '.Formula = "=ABS(" & .Cells(1).Offset(0, 9).Address(0, 0) & ")"
        ' Convert to values.
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This code made both of the columns 0. I need to to not paste the formula, but just the actual value of the cell.. so the abs(-7) willl be 7, I need it to paste just the number 7, not the actual formula

Comment: That is what the code should be doing. I also got all zero's when I started developing this code. It's just that it was looking in the wrong column. Could you once more check or exactly explain which column should be read from (`AC`?) and which column should be written to i.e. should contain the absolute values (`T`?). BTW, any of the codes will only write to column `T`, so the zeroes in column `AC` may be there from an earlier attempt of yours.

Comment: I need just the VALUES to be taken from cell AC7 and down till the end of the dataset..... and copied down into cell T7 down until the end of the data set.... cell AC7 contains   ABS( -7).... 7.... I need T7 to have the 7 NOT the formula and same thing for going down the columns

Comment: I got it to work. Your code was right.